# qt 5.8 os x catching passed parameter at GUI application open

Tags: macos, qt, user-interface, arguments

**Environment:** Qt 5.8, OS X / MacOS 12.6.8

I've written an image editing application. It has a couple of its own image formats; I'd like it to open them if they are selected to open in finder. I've told finder that they should open with the app, and after doing so the app does open when I try to open the image file, but I'm not seeing the parameter in the application. When I do this...

```
QStringList qsl = QApplication::arguments();
```

...I get a list of length 1, in which the 0th entry is the application path+name as expected, and there is no second (1th) entry, though I've right-clicked my file and selected open.

So OS X / MacOS knows to open my app, and (presumably) somehow it's telling the app which file to open, but it's not in the arguments list.

I've also tried...

```
    QStringList qsl = qApp->arguments();
```

...and doing this in `main()` instead of in `MainWindow()`.

Same results in all cases.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found it and got it working. It's pretty buried, and it's anything but obvious, but here's the key to opening a file in OS X,`QFileOpenEvent`...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileOpenEvent>

QString appParam = "";
bool caughtParam = false;

class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
    MyApplication(int &argc, char **argv)
        : QApplication(argc, argv)
    {
    }

    bool event(QEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::FileOpen)
        {
        QFileOpenEvent *openEvent = static_cast<QFileOpenEvent *>(event);
            appParam = openEvent->file();
            caughtParam = true;
        }
        return QApplication::event(event);
    }
};
```

...basically, you subclass QApplication, re-implement event as shown, then do (something) with the incoming information. Then, instead of using `QApplication` in your application, you use `MyApplication`, catch the data, and then after you're done setting up, go deal with the parameter.

Here, I've set a global flag and stored the parameter, then grab it later.

This works for *one* parameter, which is what I was after. Attempting to open two files results in a complaint from OS X.

**If you're doing cross-compiling to windows, you'd need to conditionally compile this in and just use `QApplication` there; according to the docs, this bit of arcana is implemented for OS X only.**